# How to install INFORMIX (IDS) 11.50 in CENTOS 5.4

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, database, informix

Getting ERROR: The wizard cannot continue because of the following error: could not load wizard specified in /wizard.inf (104)

Solution: Uninstall everything related with java and jre.  Then, download the lastest version of jre for linux x86 or x64, rpm.bin one. And follow these instructions http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml "To install the Linux RPM (self-extracting) file".

Make a user and group informix (as root), then uncompress the (informix package).tar in /opt/informix that you have created. And tun ./ids_install, and GUI will work ok.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure it quite fits in the Q&A mould as written, but good advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not too lat, give a shot on this...

once the .tar is uncompressed to a folder, get on it and run

./ids_install (-gui/-console) -javahome .jvm.bin

you'll have to choose between gui or console depending on your needs and likes, i've done it with the console and is quite straight (with the help of a blog as guide :D )

The .jvm.bin is a java machine packet with IDS just in case, i've read it on the below mentioned blog...
http://paraafuera.blogspot.com/2008/08/instalando-informix.html (spanish)